# Scroll through the spreadsheet to today's date using google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My google spreadsheet consists of columns:

- A: Date

  1. **16.07.2020**
  2. **17.07.2020**
  3. **18.07.2020**
- B, C, D: Other information

I need a script that when you open the document will automatically scroll through the table to today's date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Today:

```
function gotoTodaysDate() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheets()[0];//most left sheet
  const shsr=2;//data start row
  const shsc=1;//date column
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,shsc,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues();
  const dates=vs.map(function(r){return r[0];});//flattened
  const td=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd.MM.yyyy");//current date string
  const idx=dates.indexOf(td);
  sh.getRange(idx+shsr,1).activate();
}
```

Installable onOpen Trigger:

```
function createOnOpenTrigger() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isTrigger('gotoTodaysDate')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('gotoTodaysDate').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onOpen().create();
  }
}
```

Helper Function:
Keeps you from creating more that one trigger for a given function

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I just need to put all the functions in the script editor? If so, then I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: Here is an example [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aQO9o4u0UuGxUxa0qz58WaPmNa_pcUVAEQJHS1nvT-Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I mean I added a script to an editor, open a document and nothing happens

Comment: Did you run `createOnOpenTrigger()`

Comment: We assume that you know something about programming here.  Or atleast that you are trying to learn.  Sometimes it is required for you to do a little thinking on your own.

Comment: I did. I solved the problem. This was due to the fact that the column format was "date", I set it "plain text" and it works now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds Good Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to have a script do that.

If your dates are in reverse order (i.e., oldest up top to newest at the bottom), and you're just trying to get to the most recent date at the bottom, you can click in cell A1 and hit the Ctrl key along with the down-arrow key (i.e., Ctrl-▼) on your keyboard, and you'll be taken there.

Comment: There are empty rows in the spreadsheet so this method does not work for me

Comment: Ah. Well, it looks like Cooper is on point to help you out with the onEdit function. Good luck.